# How to join a camera to an object?

Tags: objects, camera

I'm modeling a phone and need to have a camera positioned where the phone camera is, when I try to join the camera and object it fails with a message telling me the camera doesn't have any mesh data. And all my google searching just brings up how to make a camera track an object which to be clear is not what I am after - I need to simulate the constant position and rotation of the front camera on a phone with respect to the LCD display when the entire phone is moved.

Comment: Did you tried with parenting the camera to the object?

Comment: Thanks Carlo, so making the camera parent and then locking the camera's transform achieved what I want. If you would care to turn your comment in to an Answer I would be happy to accept it as 'The Answer'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parenting the camera to the object will solve this problem. You can do this by selecting the camera *first*, and then selecting the object you want to parent it to. You can parent by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, and then selecting **object (keep transform)**. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Select the objects and keep camera as the active object, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to do parenting.